# Automatically scrolling RecyclerView list to the bottom upon input

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'd like to scroll to the bottom of the RecyclerView list after loading the activity. Every time I send or receive message, I need to scroll to the bottom to  read the message. How can I configure it to scroll automatically when a message is sent or received?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.chatWindow_rec);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

recyclerView.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

I tried StackFromEnd, `recyclerview.ScrollToPosition(ListMessage.size())` ... with no result. How can I fix this?

Comment: when you recieve the new message do you append it to ListMessage list? and after appending do you do the ScrollToPosition?

Comment: Listmessage contain all new messages i used ScrollToPosition (ListMessage.size )) but dosn't work

Answer (score 0):

use this line in your code hope it will help you out:

```
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make sure the List<> in the Adapter was updated with a new message.

Then use RecylcerView.smoothScrollToPosition(List.size()) to scroll to the bottom of the list.

Or, use RecylcerView.smoothScrollToPosition(MessageListAdapter.getItemCount())

You should go with the second option since getItemCount() is a default method of the adapter, just remember overidde it.

```
 public static RecyclerView.LayoutManager createVerticalLayoutManager(Context context) {
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context
            , LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
            , false);
    return layoutManager;
}
```

And make you RecyclerView with width and height as match_parent.

Call update on the Adapter when append a new message

```
        mMessageAdapter.notifyItemChanged(mMessageAdapter.getItemCount());
```

The code line above just update the adapter with specified the latest item.

Comment: The list updated with new messages and i used smoothscrooltoposition lise.size but dosnt work

Comment: In your adapter, make sure you are override getItemCount(). In that method, just return the list.size().

Then use scrollToPosition with Adapter.getItemCount().

Make sure you call the method after you append the latest message into your message list.

Comment: I doubt that your message list does not display anything right? Because the RecyclerView MUST have a correct setup with LayoutManager.

I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1st write a function to return number of items in adapter then after adding data to adapter use

```
    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getCount()-1);
```